# Mindful of competition for the loyalty of its ally

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "Americans,increasingly consumed by fears that China poses a commercial and military threat, should be mindful of competition for the loyalties of its oldest ally." [Economist]

The context was that not only European should be conscious of China's investments in the EU that caused Greece or Czech Republic supported China, but also Americans.

My question is if this understanding is correct that "Americans should be mindful of competition for **showing loyalties to China by the EU**".

Comment: Why no one has replied the question? Is it too political and e.g. I should have replaced name of the countries with letters A, B, etc.?

Comment: It likely has nothing to do with politics. Sometimes questions just don't get answered quickly. You may get better results with a different title. Your current title provides the phrase that you are asking about, but it does not provide any context for the question. For example, "Understanding the meaning of the phrase 'mindful of competition for the loyalty of its ally'" clarifies what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Americans, increasingly consumed by fears that China poses a commercial and military threat, should be mindful of competition for the loyalties of its oldest ally.

The sentence is saying that China is now attempting to earn the loyalty of America's ally. Traditionally America's ally (I assume the EU in this case) would be expected to show loyalty to America. However, as China competes for this loyalty, the ally may end up favoring China instead.